# Can't append all rows to QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

Here is code.

```
QList<QStandardItem*> items;
items.append(allData);
QStandardItemModel.appendRow(items);
```

But, it only set first row of items..

Answer (score 1):

Using appendRow() with a list of items, the items are used for the columns of a single row.
If you want to have each item create a new row, use [appendRows()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstandarditem.html#appendRows) (notice the plural).